# dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer in C

Tags: c, void-pointers, dereference

So I have those in a .h

```
stable.h

// The symbol table.
typedef struct stable_s *SymbolTable;

// Data stored.
typedef union {
  int i;
  char *str;
  void *p;
} EntryData;

// Return struct for stable_insert.
typedef struct {
  int new;  // Was a new entry created?
  EntryData *data;  // Data associated with entry.
} InsertionResult;

etc
```

Then in my .c

```
stable.c

etc

typedef struct {
    char *key;
    EntryData data;
} Entry;

struct stable_s { /* Indice hash */
    char index;
    int size;
    void *pointer;
};

etc

EntryData *stable_find(SymbolTable table, const char *key){
    int k;
    char c;

    if (key[0] >= 'A' && key[0] <= 'Z')
        c = table[(key[0] - 65)].index;
    else if (key[0] >= 'a' && key[0] <= 'z')
        c = table[(key[0] - 141)].index;
    else
        c = table[26].index;

    c -= 65;

    if (table[c].size == 0)
        return NULL;

    k = busca_binaria(table[c].pointer, table[c].size, key);
    if (strcmp(table[c]->pointer[k]->key, key) == 0)
        return table[c]->pointer[k]->data;

    return NULL;
}
```

And `gcc -std=c99 stable.c -o stable` is giving me those errors:

> ```
> stable2.c: In function ‘stable_find’:
> stable2.c:128:24: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct stable_s’)
>  if (strcmp(table[c]->pointer[k]->key, key) == 0) 
> stable2.c:129:24: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct stable_s’)
>      return table[c]->pointer[k]->data;
> ```

What am I missing? I'm really lost in the syntax.

Comment: What's `SymbolTable`?

Comment: Is your compiler's default `char` type `unsigned char`? Because of this expression `key[0] - 141`

Comment: @EugeneSh.: See stable.h above: `typedef struct stable_s *SymbolTable;`

Comment: @FredLarson Right. My Ctrl-F betrayed me...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: But that's still weird, since `struct stable_s` is defined in the .cpp file.

Comment: Anyway. `table[whatever]` is a struct, not a pointer, so don't use `->` on it..

Comment: @WeatherVane gcc version 4.9.2

Comment: Looking at the above pair of lines, where you subtract `65` (although you should subtract `'A'`) should the offensive line be `c = table[(key[0] - 'a'].index;`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Now looks like this stable2.c:128:5: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     if (strcmp(table[c].pointer[k]->key, key) == 0)

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm trying to build a table using only [A-Z] and "others"

Comment: Well I give up, if all you can do is give indirect answers to my comments.

Comment: `...pointer` is a void pointer, so `...pointer[k]` is meaningless.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm sorry. I'm not an expert, so I don't know how to check what you asked.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But how should I cast it? I've tried a bunch of stuff :/

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, pointer is a pointer to Entry, which has a char *key. I'm trying to compare this key to a string received as an argument.

Comment: Let's rewind a bit. When the character is in the range `'A'..'Z'` you subtracted `65` to get an array index from `0...`. Although `65` *is* the ASCII value for `'A'` you should really have subtracted `'A'` to be more foolproof. Moving on to the next test of lowercase in the range `'a'..'z'` you subtracted `141` which has no relation to the ASCII value for `'a'` which is `97`. So the lesson is, don't subtract a "magic number" like `65` or `141` but subtract `'A'` or `'a'`.

Comment: LOL 141 is the oct for 'a'. Corrections made. Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us look at these lines:

```
k = busca_binaria(table[c].pointer, table[c].size, key);
if (strcmp(table[c]->pointer[k]->key, key) == 0)
    return table[c]->pointer[k]->data;
```

What is `table`? It is `struct stable_s *`

So

```
table[c]
```

is a `struct stable_s` - and it is **not** a pointer.

So back to the lines:

```
k = busca_binaria(table[c].pointer, table[c].size, key);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  Correct as table[c] is a struct stable_s

if (strcmp(table[c]->pointer[k]->key, key) == 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           Wrong as table[c] is not a point

    return table[c]->pointer[k]->data;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           Wrong as table[c] is not a point
```

There seems to be other problems in your code (like dereferencing `void*) but the above should relate to the compiler errors.

Maybe this line:

```
if (strcmp(table[c]->pointer[k]->key, key) == 0)
```

should be:

```
if (strcmp(((Entry*)table[c].pointer)[k].key, key) == 0)
```

but I can't be sure as you haven't posted code that tells this.

And maybe this line:

```
return table[c]->pointer[k]->data;
```

should be:

```
return &(((Entry*)table[c].pointer)[k].data);
```

Comment: Then I get those errors: stable2.c:128:33: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
     if (strcmp((table[c].pointer[k]->key), key) == 0)

stable2.c:128:5: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     if (strcmp((table[c].pointer[k]->key), key) == 0)

stable2.c:129:32: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
         return table[c].pointer[k]->data;

stable2.c:129:9: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
         return table[c].pointer[k]->data;

Comment: @Paul - True, you can't dereference a `void*` - you need to know the type of the original pointer and cast back to that type. How do you initialize `pointer`?

Comment: I only initialize it if needed in a stable_insert function

Comment: if (table[c].size == 0) {
            table[c].pointer = malloc (sizeof (Entry*));
            table[c].size++;
            k = 0;
        }

Comment: Should pointer be Entry **pointer, since it's pointing to an Entry *data?

Comment: @Paul - hard to say from the posted code. It seems that `pointer` is supposed be a `Entry*` but .... need more code to tell. Did you try what I suggested? What result did you get?

Comment: LOL IT WORKED FOR THE STRCMP!

Comment: Any idea on how to return the EntryData *? :D

Comment: Incompatible types when returning type ‘EntryData’ but ‘union EntryData *’ was expected :/

Comment: Can you help with this last one? :/ table[c].pointer[k]->key = key;

Comment: What's the syntax to save the key? :/

Comment: @Paul - Same princip, I guess: `table[c].pointer[k]->key = key` -> `((Entry*)table[c].pointer)[k].key = key`